# ThreadPool exceptions in gevent do not get returned

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, gevent

I'm using gevent on Python 2.7 to do some multithreaded work.  However, I am unable to catch exceptions that are raised in the spawned methods.  I am using the `.get()` method on the returned `AsyncResult` object (returned when calling the `.spawn()` method on the thread pool).

Per the gevent documentation: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.event.html#gevent.event.AsyncResult.get:

> **`get(block=True, timeout=None)`**
>
> Return the stored value or raise the exception.
>
> If this instance already holds a value or an exception, return or raise it immediately.

However, instead of returning the exception, `.get()` returns `NoneType`.  Additionally, in the console, the exception details are printed out.  Instead, `.get()` should return the Exception back.

Here is some sample code and corresponding output that showcases this:

```
from gevent import threadpool

def this_will_fail():
    raise Exception('This will fail')

result_list = []
for i in range(1,5):
    tpool = threadpool.ThreadPool(5)
    result_list.append(tpool.spawn(this_will_fail))

tpool.join()

for result in result_list:
    try:
        returned_object = result.get()
        print type(returned_object)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'This is not running for some reason...'
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/threadpool.py", line 193, in _worker
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in this_will_fail
Exception: This will fail
(<ThreadPool at 0x107c79e50 0/1/5>, <function this_will_fail at 0x107c848c0>) failed with Exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/threadpool.py", line 193, in _worker
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in this_will_fail
Exception: This will fail
(<ThreadPool at 0x107c99210 0/1/5>, <function this_will_fail at 0x107c848c0>) failed with Exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/threadpool.py", line 193, in _worker
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in this_will_fail
Exception: This will fail
(<ThreadPool at 0x107c99410 0/1/5>, <function this_will_fail at 0x107c848c0>) failed with Exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/threadpool.py", line 193, in _worker
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in this_will_fail
Exception: This will fail
(<ThreadPool at 0x107c99610 0/1/5>, <function this_will_fail at 0x107c848c0>) failed with Exception

<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a bug in gevent?

**EDIT:** `concurrent.futures` doesn't have this problem.  While that is an acceptable solution for my use case, I would still like to understand why gevent doesn't properly return the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we had the same problem with the gevent threadpool. We are using a solution which wrap the function to return exceptions as result, and raise it again when we want to use the result from the AsynResult.

```py
class _ExceptionWrapper:
    def __init__(self, exception, error_string, tb):
        self.exception = exception
        self.error_string = error_string
        self.tb = tb

class wrap_errors(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = self.func
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return _ExceptionWrapper(*sys.exc_info())

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.func)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.func)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.func, item)

def get_with_exception(g, block=True, timeout=None):
    result = g._get(block, timeout)
    if isinstance(result, _ExceptionWrapper):
        # raise the exception using the caller context
        raise result.error_string, None, result.tb
    else:
        return result

def spawn(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    # wrap the function
    fn = wrap_errors(fn)
    g = threadpool.spawn(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    # and the asynresult
    g._get = g.get
    g.get = types.MethodType(get_with_exception, g)
    return g
```